# Windows Mobile hide Task Bar and Menu Bar

Tags: c++, windows, mobile, windows-mobile

On Windows Mobile device, I want to hide the Task Bar and Menu Bar.  I have the code below from google search, but it does not hide the icons on Task Bar.  If possible I would like to hide all the icons when hiding the Task Bar.

```
void TaskBar(BOOL lock)
{
    MessageInfo(TEXT("inside TaskBar()"));
    if(lock == TRUE)
    {
        CWnd* pWnd = CWnd::FindWindowW(TEXT("HHTaskBar"), NULL);

        if(pWnd)
        {
            pWnd->ShowWindow(SW_HIDE);
            pWnd->EnableWindow(FALSE);
        }
    }
    else if(lock == FALSE)
    {
        CWnd* pWnd = CWnd::FindWindowW(TEXT("HHTaskBar"), NULL);

        if(pWnd)
        {
            //pWnd->ShowWindow(SW_SHOW);
            pWnd->ShowWindow(SW_SHOWNORMAL);
            pWnd->EnableWindow(TRUE);
        }
    }
}
```

For hiding the Menu Bar, I found on google that I can do it through registry.  I have Windows Mobile 6.5.3, but these registries do not exist:

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Shell\BubbleTiles]
"TextModeEnabled"=dword:00000001
"HardwareStartKeyEnabled"=dword:00000001
"HardwareDoneKeyEnabled"=dword:00000001
```

So how can I hide the Menu Bar as well.

thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As for taskbar use:

```
SHFullScreen(hWnd, SHFS_HIDETASKBAR);
SHFullScreen(hWnd, SHFS_HIDESIPBUTTON);
SHFullScreen(hWnd, SHFS_HIDESTARTICON);
```

where hWnd is your main frame window handle

I am not sure abour menubar, it either can be hidden by not defining your menu in resources or by moving your app window above it.

Comment: thanks.  It seems for the Menu Bar, I have to create registry then reboot the device then it will be ok.

Comment: And is there anything I need to include? My Windows Mobile 6.5 SDK does not know the function.error C3861: 'SHFullScreen': identifier not found